Changing target branch on GitHub PR has added additional commits
I have the following git branch status
o---o-------------------6  main
     \                 / <- via squash
      1---2---3---4---5  feature a
               \
                x---o---o  feature b


There was one branch feature a
Feature b branched of feature a and added some commits (it wanted updates from feature a branch but additions weren't related to feature a) AND THE PR TARGETED the feature a branch
feature a got squash merged into main
I now want to squash merge feature b into main

What I have done so far

Changed the PRs target branch to main

However this has left the state now in
o---o-------------------6---?  main
     \                     /
      1---2---3---x---o---o  feature b

Where the first 3 commits of feature a are now under the feature b branch. It I merge now, the changes from 1,2,3 will look like they came from the feature b PR.
What I want to do is somehow set the base of commit x to 6 (aka not include 1,2,3)?
o---o ... 6----------?  main
          \         /
           x---o---o  feature b

What commands do I use to do this (maybe rebase?). How can I keep the history clean and not lose anything?

You need to clean feature-b from commits that made up feature-a. git rebase commit-3-id-or-old-tip-of-feature-a feature-b --onto main

Another cautionary tale about squashing commits. Should only be used knowingly, for good reasons, not as a default practice.

@eftshift0 already gave you the fix. I just want to nitpick one sentence which might help your understanding: "It I merge now, the changes from 1,2,3 will look like they came from the feature b PR." Actually, if you merge now, commits 1,2,3 will be brought in by that merge, but the changes from those commits will not show as being brought in, because the changes are already there on main. So it will look confusing because it will appear that those commits are being brought in for no reason, if someone were to look closely at those commits.

@TTT is that still true if it is a squash merge?

@Ben Yup; still true for a squash. Note you can try a regular rebase: git switch feature-b followed by git rebase main, and if you do that it might work because the first three commits might "fall out" since they would probably make empty commits. But eftshift0's advanced rebase definitely will work because it's skipping those 3 commits and not even attempting to rebase them.
